# RouteCollection.Ignore Method Syntax

Tags: asp.net, routes, telerik, url-routing

I am using routing with asp.net 4.0 and Telerik controls with routing. We are using too many editors and spell checkers of telerik controls. These controls require

```
Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx
Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd
```

These 2 files are calling from different locations.

I want to write a general syntax for

```
routes.Ignore("Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx");
```

Right now I am writing too many different paths in the Ignore string.

I want a general syntax for all paths which have "Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx". But HOW?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the **DialogHandlerUrl** and **SpellCheckSettings-AjaxUrl** properties of the RadEditors to *"~/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx"* and *"~/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd"* respectively. This way the requests for those files will always have the same base URL (in the root folder of your application) and you will need to write only one ignore to the routes collection. The downside is that you need to modify all your RadEditor instances in the application and add the two properties.